# Where are an iPhone app's NSLog statements recorded on Windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, nslog

I am trying to debug an issue one of my testers is facing. The tester is on a Windows and I have put in some NSLog statements in my code to analyze the issue at hand.

On a Mac, when I sync my device with iTunes, I can see the NSLog statements in Console.app. But where does in show up on a PC?

I know where to find the crash logs. But the app doesn't crash, so thats not going to help much.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [iPhone configuration utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) - that is available for both, windows and mac os.

Comment: Thanks. Also found out that the Event Viewer shows all the log messages.